# How can fix CertVerifyProcBuiltin errors while using selenium on Chrome?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I have a issue about selenium library usage. When i try to employ webdriver.Chrome i am getting some bugs related certificates errors.Like this

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58269/devtools/browser/7e84b5d6-29c2-4dcf-9b3a-422a2ec968ed
----- Certificate i=0 (CN=*.google.com) -----                                               r docs.google.com failed:
ERROR: No matching issuer found


[7320:17704:0718/155157.224:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(702)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for www.gstatic.com failed:                                                                   r www.gstatic.com failed:
----- Certificate i=0 (CN=*.gstatic.com) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found
```

I try to add some options.

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--headless')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
chromeOptions.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

Comment: Have you been able to solve this @Jossoft?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried,

```
--disable-proxy-certificate-handler
```

option in your `ChromeOptions`.

Like below

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-proxy-certificate-handler")
```

Comment: Yeah i tried to add this option argument however i didn't reach the result what i want.

Comment: Have you also added `--disable-content-security-policy` ?

Comment: There is nothing change. This error appear consistently. [7320:17704:0718/155157.224:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(702)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for www.gstatic.com failed:                                                                   r www.gstatic.com failed:
----- Certificate i=0 (CN=*.gstatic.com) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found

Comment: I used `--ignore-certificate-errors --disable-proxy-certificate-handler` which worked but still complained.  I am on a corporate network that changes the SSL certificates.